# PHP version of ASP.NET's SqlCacheDependency

Tags: php, asp.net, mysql, caching, sqlcachedependency

I find the SqlCacheDependency very useful when writing C# ASP.NET applications, and would love to use something similar in my PHP applications. Can anyone suggest something?

**SqlCacheDependency caches the page page output forever, until the specified table(s) are modified in the database.**

Here's the basic jist of what happens in ASP.NET:

```
SqlCacheDependency SqlDep = null; 

// Check the Cache for the SqlSource key. 
// If it isn't there, create it with a dependency 
// on a SQL Server table using the SqlCacheDependency class. 
if (Cache["MyCache"] == null) { 
    SqlDep = new SqlCacheDependency("DatabaseName", "TableName"); 

    // Perform action to be cached ...
    var result = DatabaseIntensiveFunction();
    Cache.Insert("MyCache", result, SqlDep);
} 

else { 
    // The data was retrieved from the Cache.
}

// Output page from cache.
Output(Cache["MyCache"]);
```

So does anyone know of any MySql table dependency technique? - much cleaner than time-based caching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use something like [Memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or [APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) for this?

Edit: I also just found the [MySQLnd Query Cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd-qc.php) plugin for 5.3.3.